# How to set Material Dark Theme in Qt QML (QtQuick 2)?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, material-design, qtquick2

I want to set Material Dark Theme for my application in QtQuick2.
I followed this official docs:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html

And applied one line in my main.cpp (changed nothing else from auto-generated code):

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickStyle>

#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);


    //set GUI style theme here
    QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");




    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Which will add the default material theme successfully, which looks as expected:
Material default Theme:
[image: Material default Theme]

And now I want to apply the dark theme, which is not stated in the docs. I tried to change the String from "Material" to "Material.Dark" and similiar descriptions, which did not work. I also can't find a "setTheme" function or similiar on the QQuickStyle Object, which makes me a bit clueless.

Can somebody give me a hint on how to apply the dark theme to material style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution is to use the environment variable `QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_MATERIAL_THEME` (See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-environment.html):

```
qputenv("QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE", QByteArray("Material"));
qputenv("QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_MATERIAL_THEME", QByteArray("Dark"));

QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
```

You can also use the qtquickcontrols2.conf file(See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-configuration.html)

**qtquickcontrols2.conf**

```
[Controls]
Style=Material

[Material]
Theme=Dark
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the first solution and I think it works.

Comment: First solution does not work for me. The theme still switches to dark/light theme depending on the system setting, even changes at runtime when I switch the setting. Also, can't fiure out how to add the conf file to my project because I am using CMake and the QT page for the conf file only shows how to add it to a .pro project. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-configuration.html

Comment: See https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/examples/quickcontrols/gallery?h=6.6