# Qt Quick2 Material Dark Theme looks buggy/unreadable

Tags: qt, qml, material-design, qtquick2

I applied Material Dark Theme on my application as recommended on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67482325/how-to-set-material-dark-theme-in-qt-qml-qtquick-2):

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickStyle>

#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    qputenv("QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE", QByteArray("Material"));
    qputenv("QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_MATERIAL_THEME", QByteArray("Dark"));

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

And my main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 145
        y: 70
        width: 151
        height: 90
        text: qsTr("Button")
    }

    RoundButton {
        id: roundButton
        x: 401
        y: 120
        text: "+"
    }

    CheckBox {
        id: checkBox
        x: 157
        y: 297
        text: qsTr("Check Box")
    }

    Slider {
        id: slider
        x: 345
        y: 232
        value: 0.5
    }

    DelayButton {
        id: delayButton
        x: 377
        y: 344
        text: qsTr("Delay Button")
    }

    Switch {
        id: switch1
        x: 151
        y: 409
        text: qsTr("Switch")
    }
}
```

While default material works as expected, if I change to material dark it looks like this:
Material dark looks buggy:
[image: Material dark looks buggy]

I am pretty sure it shouldn't look like this. Did I miss to install something or do I need to import something additionally?

Using qtcreator on Windows, qml objects are just random unchanged controls.

Comment: I think the main problem is the background not being black (which can still be considered a bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That *should* work with the `Window` from Qt Quick. Please create a bug report for that. Using `ApplicationWindow` does work though.

Comment: Can confirm ApplicationWindow works. Thank you.