Dark mode issue with Qml on Android
For some reason the dark palette is not taken into account on Android. Here a code snippet:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    SystemPalette { id: myPalette; colorGroup: SystemPalette.Active }
    color: myPalette.window

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Column {
        Label {
            text: "Label" //KDE/BreezeDark: white on dark; Android/Dark: black on black
        }
        Text {
            text: "Text" //KDE/BreezeDark: black on dark; Android/Dark: black on black
        }
        Button {
            text: "Button" //KDE/BreezeDark: white on dark; Android/Dark: black on light
        }
    }
}

I can work around with derived controls where I explicitly set the color but shouldn't this be solved natively? Or is my approach wrong?

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67482325/how-to-set-material-dark-theme-in-qt-qml-qtquick-2
